# How to handle custom autowired objects in Spring 2.5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an old project that I need to integrate with Spring 2.5.x (3.0 is not possible).

I have created a bean, that have to initializate its field userSession by itself:

```
public class SomeBean {
    UserSession userSession;

    @PostContrust
    public void init() {
        HttpSession session = WebContext.current().getSession();
        userSession = (UserSession) session.getAttribute("userSession");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write some kind of autowiring handler that will resolve userSession and pass it for autowiring to Spring, so my bean looks just like:

```
public class SomeBean {
    @Autowire UserSession userSession;
}
```

and the handler like:

```
public class AutowireHanlder {
    public boolean isCandidate(Class<?> type) {
        return type.equals(UserSession.class);
    }

    public Object resolve(Class<?> type) {
        HttpSession session = WebContext.current().getSession();
        return (UserSession) session.getAttribute("userSession");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using a session-scoped `FactoryBean`:

```
public class UserSessionFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<UserSession> {

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return UserSession.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected UserSession createInstance() throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = WebContext.current().getSession();
        return (UserSession) session.getAttribute("userSession");   
    }

}
```

Define `UserSessionFactoryBean` as a bean:

```
<bean scope="session" class="com.xyz.UserSessionFactoryBean"/>
```

... and then you should then be able to autowire `UserSession` into any other bean.

The complexity here is that `UserSessionFactoryBean` has to be [session-scoped](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-session) (see docs on [bean scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)), since it must return a new value for each `HttpSession`. This means that any bean it is autowired into must *also* be session-scoped, otherwise it'll fail.  You can get around this restriction using [scoped-proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection).